# Replacing NAN in a dataframe with unique key

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

df

```
 Index key1 | key2 | key3 | value1 | Value2   
 0    1     | 3    | 4    | 6      |  4 
 1    1     | 3    | 4    | Nan    |  3 
 2    1     | 2    | 3    | 8      |  6
 3    1     | 2    | 3    | Nan    |  5
 4    5     | 7    | 1    | Nan    |  2
```

For the value with the same keys (key1, key2, key3), I want to use numeric value and whenever there is no numeric value I want to remove the row. For value2, I simply want the sum.

Desired df

```
Index key1 | key2 | key3 | value1 | value2    
 0    1    | 3    | 4    | 6      | 7
 2    1    | 2    | 3    | 8      | 11
```

Retaining the correct index is not important.

Comment: There is only one non NaN value per group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one non NaN per group use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non `NaN` value and also aggregate `sum`:

```
df['value1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value1'], errors='coerce')

df = (df.groupby(['key1','key2','key3'], as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg(value1 = ('value1','first'),Value2 = ('Value2','sum'))
        .dropna(subset=['value1']))

print (df)
   key1  key2  key3  value1  Value2
0     1     3     4     6.0       7
1     1     2     3     8.0      11
```

If possible multiple non `NaN`s values first aggregate `sum`, then remove missing rows by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), remove column fr aggregate sum and add new by `Series` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df['value1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value1'], errors='coerce')

s = df.groupby(['key1','key2','key3'])['Value2'].sum()
df = df.dropna(subset=['value1']).drop('Value2', 1).join(s, on=['key1','key2','key3'])

print (df)
   Index  key1  key2  key3  value1  Value2
0      0     1     3     4     6.0       7
2      2     1     2     3     8.0      11
```